# Error when using java 1.6.0_29

Tags: java, applet

I have made a java applet that works fine on the linux computers at school(running java 1.6.0_23). But i recently bought myself a mac and installed java 1.6.0_29 on it. The problem is, when i run the program on my new mac, i get several errors when running:

```
Dentist1 is treating patient10


Dentist0 is treating patient11
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:249)
at apple.awt.ComponentModel.handleEvent(ComponentModel.java:263)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4811)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:679)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:638)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:636)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at    java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at     java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)


Dentist1 is treating patient12
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:652)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:650)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at       java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:649)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:249)
at apple.awt.ComponentModel.handleEvent(ComponentModel.java:263)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4811)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:679)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:638)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:636)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:652)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:650)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:649)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)


Dentist0 is treating patient13


Dentist1 is treating patient14´
```

In case you wonder, the applet is supposed to simulate a dentist office with 2 dentists and 4 chairs in the waiting room. I have a secretary thread class that makes sure only 4 patients gets to enter the waiting room and that a patient can go in to the dentist if he's not busy, two dentist threads that waits for a patient and then treat them.

It seem to run fine with the first 10 patients and then i get those errors and after that it continues to run without errors. 
I don't know if its possible for you to help me with this problem without looking at my code, but i would be grateful for any advice to why this only happens with a newer java version. Is it likely there is something wrong with my code that java 1.6.0_23 won't detect?

Comment: Does the code use Swing components?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I suspect that you are calling/using unassigned objects in your code. By default they will have null value. please share your code, that will help us in figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly easy to write code which happens work. The bug is there bug doesn't show itself until you change the OS, hardware or version of Java.  A significant portion of problems which arise from upgrading from Java 5.0 to Java 6 or 6 to 7 come from these sort of bugs.

It is likely you are corrupting your Swing object model but Java 6 update 23 doesn't notice.  However, it is more likely to be a difference in the hardware/OS you are using.

I would download Java 6 update 23 to check this (or use the same version on both systems)

Comment: Thanks. I will try that, though it seem like i can't install older versions on mac..

Answer (score 0):

The code of Java classes aren't the best when it comes to handling null values. Check if you give some null values to your Swing components and change them to non-null values.